One date time formatter for 2 cases
I am trying to parse a date in format yyyyMMddHHmmss. The problem is that 'ss' part is optional so
'202308301000' and '20230830100005' are acceptable.
I defined my formatter like this:
    private static final DateTimeFormatter INPUT_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm")
        .optionalStart()
        .appendPattern("ss")
        .optionalEnd()
        .toFormatter();

The problem is that it does not work and fails for 20230830100005 where the 'ss' part exists. I tried different approaches but could not manage to make it work...
INPUT_FORMATTER.parse("202308301000");
INPUT_FORMATTER.parse("20230830100005");

Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20230830100005' could not be parsed at index 0

Anyone has idea how to do it ?

"fails" doesn't tell us how you're using it

The Answer by Michael is correct. But an ever better solution: Educate the publisher of your data about using only standard ISO 8601 formats for exchanging date-time values textually. Then your entire problem goes away, as does the need to define a custom formatting pattern.

I might be lazy and just use DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[uuuuMMddHHmmss][uuuuMMddHHmm]"). If the first pattern succeeds, all is fine, and if it doesn’t, the second will be tried. So it works with both 202308301000 and 20230830100005.

The problem is that the year part is variable width. yyyy in the pattern is not matching something 4 digits, like the 4 characters in the pattern. It accepts the year 10000, for example, even though that's 5 digits.
With the variable width thing at the start, and the optional part at the end, and no literals anywhere to detect the boundaries between fields, the parser is failing to detect what we as humans can see intuitively: that '2023' is the year part.
You can explicitly define that the year part is exactly 4 digits like this:
DateTimeFormatter INPUT_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 4)
    .appendPattern("MMddHHmm")
    .optionalStart()
    .appendPattern("ss")
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter();

Dates before year 1000 will need to be padded with 0s, dates after year 10000 won't work.
